# Xamarin.Android push notifications GCM to Azure Notification Hub

Tags: android, azure, google-cloud-messaging, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Android application that I've configured for GCM using [this Xamarin guide](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/notifications/android/remote_notifications_in_android/)
The app is able to receive the notifications this way.
BUT, when I put the GCM API key in notification Hub, and send the notification via Azure, its not received in the app.

The app registers with GCM. Do I need to register with Azure Notification Hub? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. I had to register with Azure notification hub too.
If someone is stuck, follow this:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/partner-xamarin-notification-hubs-android-get-started/

Or, follow the example given in Xamarin's "Azure Messaging" component here:
https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/azure-messaging